# Limitar a quantidade de arquivos que sera exibido em um diretório

Tags: php

Galera preciso limitar a quantidade de arquivos que será exibido em um determinado diretório.

Esse é meu código em php que lista os arquivos do meu diretório :

```
<?php 

$diretorio = getcwd(). "/arquivos" ; 

$ponteiro  = opendir($diretorio);

while ($nome_itens = readdir($ponteiro)) 

  $itens[] = $nome_itens;

sort ($itens);

foreach ( $itens as $listar )

if ( $listar!="." && $listar!="..")

print '.$listar.';

?>
```

Existe algum modo de incrementar esse código para que ele exiba somente os 5 últimos arquivos enviados para esse diretório ?

Answer (score 0):

Se considerarmos a data de modificacão do arquivo, podemos fazer o seguinte:

```
// Recupera a lista de todos os arquivos:
$files = glob("/arquivos/*");

// Ordena os arquivos pela data de modificacão:
usort($files, function ($a, $b) { return filemtime($a) < filemtime($b); });

// Pega apenas os cinco últimos modificados:
$files = array_slice($files, 0, 5);
```

Basicamente, a funcão `glob` faz sozinha o que seu código faz: pega a lista completa dos arquivos. Atente-se ao caractere `*` em seu parâmetro, pois ele é um coringa que faz com que todos os arquivos sejam listados. Se desejasse arquivos de apenas uma extensão específica, poderia fazer `/arquivos/*.pdf`, por exemplo. A funcão `usort` ordena a lista de arquivos conforme a data de modificacão dos arquivos, que é recuperada através da funcão `filemtime`. Finalmente, é extraído apenas os cinco primeiros arquivos da lista.

Comment: Vlw Anderson é esse código mesmo, agora me ajude pra só exibir o nome do arquivo.
Ex:
Com esse código ele exibe:
arquivos/doc.txt
Eu preciso que ele exiba:
doc.txt

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Basta utilizar a função `explode` utilizando o caractere `/` como delimitador e obter a última posição do array. Ou melhor, utilizar a função `pathinfo`.